# How do I force logout user via JWT cookie on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a problem when I logout on node application my front end (public side).

I am handling logout via a client side button click event to call client side signout() using the script below, but the page its supposed to redirect to in the pug templates still shows them as logged in,  until AFTER another page refresh ! In fact the redirect never seems to happen!!

```js
export const signout = async () => {
    console.log('Client Side Logout');
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/api/v1/users/logout',
        });
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data.status === 'success') {
            showAlert('success', 'Signed out successfully !');
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                location.assign('/');
            }, 1000);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response);
        showAlert('error', 'Error logging out! Try again.');
    }
};
```

This function calls express server side route '/api/v1/users/logout' to basically set the JWT to a value of 'loggedout' to invalidate the JWT and effectively logout the user.

```js
exports.logout = (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('jwt', 'loggedout', {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: req.secure || req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https',
    });
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
};
```

The http status always seems to be 204 and the Client side signout() function never seems to get to the 'Signed out successfully !' console log. Seems like a cache issue.

Tearing my hair out !!! Really appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: does `showAlert` get called? also, where is the user when they click `logout`? perhaps browser behaves strangely when you try to redirect from `/` to `/`

Comment: Yes, `GET` requests are cached by default. Don't use them for actions. Make that a `POST` endpoint.

Comment: Turns out it was my bad and I forgot to preventdefault() on the button click, so was ignoring click event! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my bad and I forgot to preventdefault() on the button click, so was ignoring click event! Thanks anyway